# Creating an animation of raster layers within a QGIS map view without manually setting the time of each layer

Tags: qgis, raster, time, animation, video

I am seeking to create an animation of raster layers within a QGIS map view (preferred) or layout view with titles, etc., without manually setting the time of each layer and without exporting individual images for each layer and then using a different program to make the animation file.
Is there a method to set time stamps of raster layers automatically or alternatively to create an animation of a set of raster layers ordered in a group?
I've tried RasterTimeseriesManager and TimeManager but they are not working for me because I don't how to set the time of each raster layer. Also, I don't want this to be a long-term option - I have about 40 animate I want to animate and I want to be able to do this regularly with different image sets without manually setting the time of each image.
For these plug-ins I have tried adding layers individually and also building a virtual raster to use as the input.
The images are numbered sequentially so hopefully that makes it easier.